# How can I output elements from a list AND the number of times they have occurred in a document?

Tags: python

I am a two-day old fetus when it comes to Python and programming in general, so  I need some guidance. Basically, I am trying to write a function that will go through a list of documents and count the amount of times a particular keyword and its synonyms appear.

For reference, an "Entry" in the code refers to a class of objects with the attributes "word" and "synonyms". A Thesaurus is a list of Entry objects and a Corpus is a list of Documents, and each Document is a list of strings.

What I have managed to do is this: 
Lines 2-6 concern the creation of a list, All_words, that contains the keyword and the keyword's synonyms. 
Lines 7-12 are the problem. I can only get the function to output the FIRST Search_word in All_words and its number of occurrences.

```
def search(keyword) : #user inputs keyword
    All_words = [keyword]
    for Entry in Thesaurus: 
        if Entry.word == keyword:
            for Word in Entry.synonyms:
        All_words.append(Word) 
    for Search_word in All_words:
        count = 0
        for Document in Corpus: 
            for Word in Document:
                if Search_word == Word:
                    count = count + 1
        return Search_word, count

input = "sad"
output = search(input) 
print(output)
```

For reference, if the keyword is "sad", All_words should be: ['sad', 'upset', 'depressed', 'unhappy']
My current results are this:

```
('sad', 4)
```

I expected the results to look like this:

```
(('sad', 4), ('upset', 2), ('depressed', 2), ('unhappy', 0))
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: Use collections.Counter

Comment: Line 6 has incorrect indentation -- it should be indented one level past `for Word in Entry.synonyms:`

Comment: You appear to be appending *all* synonyms to `All_words` (and fix the indentation in that line, so it's clearer you're doing that). Then, in the next (outer) for loop, you loop over `All_words`, thus counting all synonyms, not just the "main" word ("sad" in your example).

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) may be useful, though you'll still have to avoid adding synonyms into the counter as well.

Comment: Note also that the `str` and `list` classes have a built-in `count()` method; depending on the type and size of `Document`. you might be able to do something like `Document.count(Word)` or `''.join(Document).count(Word)`.

Comment: at least one problems looks like a scoping(indentation) issue like @CalvinGodfrey mentions.

Comment: @9769953 yup, you're right after putting this into a script and running, so probably formatting problem in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your return statement -- `return Search_word, count` is inside the `for` loop. So after it finish searching for the first word, in this case `sad`, it will immediately `return` and stop execution.

You'll have to move the `return` statement to run OUTSIDE the `for` loop, and change it slightly so that it outputs results from ALL words you're searching for.

Also, just a style thing -- variable names should not start with upper case letters.

As for how to store all different synonyms and their corresponding count, see below:

```
answer = []
for Search_word in All_words:
    count = 0
    ....
    answer.append([Search_word, count])
return answer
```

Comment: Ok, I see. Do you have any tips on how to output results from ALL the words I'm searching for? When I align the `return Search_word, count` with the `for Search_word in All_words` line, my output is again only one word, "unhappy, 0".  I can't indent `return` any farther back or else I get an indentation error.

Comment: Before the final `for loop`, you could create a list that contains each synonym and corresponding count. Then inside the `for` loop, you append the data to the list. I'll edit my original answer to reflect this.